# How can we use XSLT to achieve an XML which removes unwanted data based on a pattern of string

Tags: xml, xslt, transformer-model

**Request XML:**

```
<SchoolName>
  <name>ABC International, Wisconsin</name>
  <rank>10</rank>
</SchoolName>
<SchoolName>
  <name>XYZ Primary, Las Vegas</name>
  <rank>4</rank>
</SchoolName>
<SchoolName>
  <name>Ryan Academy, Wisconsin</name>
  <rank>6</rank>
</SchoolName>
<SchoolName>
  <name>Advanced Elementary, Houston</name>
  <rank>15</rank>
</SchoolName>
```

**Target XML:**
Must only consider the schools with name containing "Wisconsin" but name should not contain "Academy". So it will just return the below:

```
<SchoolName>
  <name>ABC International, Wisconsin</name>
  <rank>1</rank>
</SchoolName>
```

Whats the best way to achieve this? How should the XSLT file for achieving this look like?

Comment: Why is this a problem? Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: The suggestion worked in removing the data but I have another problem.

I tried using the below XSLT

But it gives me a raw output but I want it in the same format as the XML.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  
      <xsl:for-each select="SchoolNames/SchoolName[name[contains(text(),'Wisconsin')]and not(name[contains(text(),'Academy')])]">
 
 <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        <xsl:value-of select="rank" /> 
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Either edit your question or - if it's "another problem" - post a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with either `xslt:if` filter

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="SchoolNames/SchoolName">
    <xsl:if test="name[contains(text(),'Wisconsin')] and not(name[contains(text(),'Academy')])">
      <!-- do something -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or select predicate:

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="SchoolNames/SchoolName[name[contains(text(),'Wisconsin')] and not(name[contains(text(),'Academy')])]">
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Actually, all you need is a *predicate*.